# cost of installing and maintaining ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server

I was wondering if anyone knows how much does a Linux support company charge to install Ubuntu server edition 12.04 and maintain the server for 1 year in the UK.

The server will be inhouse and engineers can login remotely or have to come down to the office for any hardware repairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical offers professional support for Ubuntu. More information can be found on the website.

[image]